# gdb - how to trap corruption using gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, corruption, memory-corruption

I am trying to find where/when corruption occurs in a new program.  The program is only 495 lines, and gdb is not helping me debug it. (At least, not with my current knowledge set.)  Consider the following :

```
> gdb psgrep-2020
(comments omitted)
Reading symbols from psgrep-2020...
(gdb) b 466
Breakpoint 1 at 0x3073: file psgrep-2020.c, line 466.
(gdb) run -F dnsmasq
Starting program: /usr/local/src/psgrep-2022/psgrep-2020 -F dnsmasq

Breakpoint 1, showProcess (pid=893) at psgrep-2020.c:466
466         if (printCmdline) {
(gdb) step
467             procNameFromCmdline(pid, strWork, sizeof(strWork), TRUE) ;
(gdb) p pid
$1 = 893
(gdb) p strWork
$2 = '\000' <repeats 1023 times>
(gdb) print sizeof(strWork)
$3 = 1024
(gdb) step
procNameFromCmdline (pid=0, result=0x0, resultLen=0, fullCmd=0 '\000') at psgrep-2020.c:58
58  int procNameFromCmdline(pid_t pid, char *result, int resultLen, BOOL fullCmd) {
(gdb)
```

At the inception of the called process (procNameFromCmdline) we can see that every parameter is incorrect (TRUE equates to 1 via #define).  Sometimes gdb shows this like:

```
procNameFromCmdline (pid=0, result=0x19c5b4 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x19c5b4>, resultLen=1689012, fullCmd=0 '\000')
```

I'm not trying to get someone else to find the problem for me; what I want to do is to find a way that I can detect when the program has been corrupted.  I believe that all my memset, snprintf() and so on are correctly constrained; clearly though something has gone awry.

In case it's any help and to put things in perspective, here is the surrounding code from before the call...

```
    fpProcFile = fopen(sProcPath, "rt") ; // Open the stat file for reading text
    if (fpProcFile) {
        fscanf(fpProcFile
            , "%d %s %c %d %d %d %d %d %u %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %ld %ld %ld %ld %ld "
              "%ld %llu %lu %ld %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %d %d %u "
              "%u %llu %lu %ld %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %d"
            , &(s->pid),           s->comm,       &(s->state),       &(s->ppid),        &(s->pgrp)
            , &(s->session),     &(s->tty_nr),    &(s->tpgid),       &(s->flags),       &(s->minflt)
            , &(s->cminflt),     &(s->majflt),    &(s->cmajflt),     &(s->utime),       &(s->stime)
            , &(s->cutime),      &(s->cstime),    &(s->priority),    &(s->nice),        &(s->num_threads)
            , &(s->itrealvalue), &(s->starttime), &(s->vsize),       &(s->rss),         &(s->rsslim)
            , &(s->startcode),   &(s->endcode),   &(s->startstack),  &(s->kstkesp),     &(s->kstkeip)
            , &(s->signal),      &(s->blocked),   &(s->sigignore),   &(s->sigcatch),    &(s->wchan)
            , &(s->nswap),       &(s->cnswap),    &(s->exit_signal), &(s->processor),   &(s->rt_priority)
            , &(s->policy),      &(s->delayacct_blkio_ticks)
                                               ,  &(s->guest_time),  &(s->cguest_time), &(s->start_data)
            , &(s->end_data),    &(s->start_brk), &(s->arg_start),   &(s->arg_end),     &(s->env_start)
            , &(s->env_end),     &(s->exit_code)
             ) ;
        fclose(fpProcFile) ;
        processName = s->comm ;
        memset(strWork, 0x00, sizeof(strWork)) ;
        if (printCmdline) {
            procNameFromCmdline(pid, strWork, sizeof(strWork), TRUE) ;
```

(the only %s in that fscanf points to a char[65535] and the value for that field in /fproc/893/stat has length 9 plus a terminator.  As per documentation, 16 is enough.  But that's not the point anyway.)

Is there a way?  Do I need a more professional debugger?

(Although I am not looking for someone to solve the problem of this program, it seems to have gained some interest.  In that light, I am posting the struct used within the referenced code.)  This is documented in the linux kernel source (fs/proc/array.c) and (not my version) can be seen [here][1] and many other places.

```
struct myProcStat {
    int pid ;       // Process ID
    char comm[65535] ; // Command name limited to 16 bytes
    char state ;    // R=Running S=Sleeping D=WaitingDisk Z=Zombie T=Stopped 
                    // t=TracingStopped W=Paging X=Dead x=Dead K=Wakekill
                    // W=Waking P=Parked
    int ppid ;      // Parent process ID
    int pgrp ;      // Process group ID
    int session ;   // Session ID
    int tty_nr ;    // Controlling terminal
    int tpgid ;     // Foreground process group
    unsigned int flags ; // Kernel flags
    unsigned long int minflt ; // Number of minor faults
    unsigned long int cminflt ; // Children's minor faults
    unsigned long int majflt ; // Number of major faults
    unsigned long int cmajflt ; // Children's major faults
    unsigned long int utime ; // Amount of time scheduled user mode
    unsigned long int stime ; // Amount of time scheduled kernel mode
    long int cutime ;   // Amount of time waited-for children scheduled user mode
    long int cstime ;   // Amount of time waited-for children scheduled kernel mode
    long int priority ; // Priority running real-time scheduling policy
    long int nice ;     // Nice value
    long int num_threads ; // Number of threads in this process
    long int itrealvalue ; // Time in jiffies before next SIGALARM is sent
// 21 above, 22 next ...
    unsigned long long int starttime ; // Start tine (in clock ticks) after system boot (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK))
    unsigned long int vsize ; // Virtual memory size in bytes
    long int rss ;  // Resident set size
    unsigned long int rsslim ; // Current soft limit in bytes on rss
    unsigned long int startcode ; // address above which text can be run
    unsigned long int endcode ;   // Address below which text can be run
    unsigned long int startstack ; // Address of the start (bottom) of the stack
    unsigned long int kstkesp ; // Current stack pointer from kernel perspective
    unsigned long int kstkeip ; // Current EIP (instruction pointer)
    unsigned long int signal ; // Bitmap of pending signals as a decimal number. Obsolete. use /proc/[pid]/status instead.
    unsigned long int blocked ; // Bitmap of blocked signals. Obsolete. Use /proc/[pid]/status instead
    unsigned long int sigignore ; // Bitmap of ignored signals. Obsolete, use /proc/[pid]/status instead
    unsigned long int sigcatch ; // Bitmap of caught signals.  Use /proc/[pid]/status instead
    unsigned long int wchan ; // Channel in which process is waiting. Use with /proc/[pid]/wchan
    unsigned long int nswap ; // Number of pages swapped (not maintained - ignore)
    unsigned long int cnswap ; // Number of child process pages swapped (not maintained - ignore)
    int exit_signal ; // Signal to be sent to parent upon death
    int processor ;   // CPU last executed on
    unsigned int rt_priority ; // Real-time scheduling priority
    unsigned int policy ; // Scheduling policy for real-time scheduling
    unsigned long long int delayacct_blkio_ticks ; // Aggregated block I/O delays, in clock ticks
    unsigned long int guest_time ; // Guest time (time spent running virtual CPU for guest OS)
    unsigned long int cguest_time ; // Guest time of processes' children
    unsigned long int start_data ; // Address above which program BSS data are placed
    unsigned long int end_data ; // Address below which program BSS data are placed
    unsigned long int start_brk ; // Address above which program heap can be expanded
    unsigned long int arg_start ; // Address above which program command-line arguments (argv) are placed
    unsigned long int arg_end ; // Address below which argv are placed
    unsigned long int env_start ; // Address above which environment is placed
    unsigned long int env_end ; // Address below which environment is placed
    int exit_code ; // The thread's exit status in form reported by waitpid(2)
    } ;


  [1]: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/proc/array.c
```

Comment: OMG.. is it a production code? This is awful. How can one even check if the `fscanf` call is correct? Count all these `%ld`s and `%lu`s?

Comment: Thanks for your opinion @EugeneSh.  Do you have any contribution to the question?

Comment: As Eugene pointed out, the `fscanf` is so massive, that it's difficult to verify that it returned the correct number of matches. (i.e.) The _program_ should check the return value of `fscanf`. Also, because you didn't post your `struct` definition or sample data input, it's difficult to know if a given field of the `struct` has sufficient space. Did you compile with `-Wall` to have the compiler check the `fscanf` for mismatches in arguments vs. the format specifiers and correct number of arguments? I'd do all that desk checking _first_, before resorting to `gdb`. And, post more code.

Comment: `gdb` [or any debugger] may not be suited to the problem if (e.g.) you're trying to [in the middle of the `struct`] get a field that overflows because (e.g.) you're trying to store `abcdefghi` into `foo` given: `char foo[5]; char bar[8];`  Otherwise, `gdb` is more than powerful enough. If you had to, you could single step through the `fscanf`. For the `foo` example, instead of `%s %s`, you may want: `%4s %s`. But, even then, you'll get `abcd` in `foo` and `efghi` in `bar`--not what you want.

Comment: How much space did you allow for `comm`, since it can arbitrarily large (e.g.) `(my_program_name_is_very_long)`? Or `(my program name is very long and contains spaces)`. That can _not_ be matched with `%s` as it will _only_ get `my` and the remainder will mess up the rest of the format. So, you can _not_ use `fscanf` to parse this. That's why the comm field has parentheses, so you can grab everything between the `(` and the `)`.

Comment: But, programs _are_ allowed to have parens in their names. So, to even do the `()` parsing, you have to read the _entire_ line. Then, use `strrchr(buf,')')` to find the trailing `)` because a program could be: `(foo ))` from `/proc/X/stat` and we want: `foo )` in the `comm` field

Comment: Thanks, Craig.  It is well documented that the Linux kernel, through a decision made long ago, will store exacrly 16 bytes in the comm field of the stat file.  I will post the struct.  in this case, though, this field contains "(dnsmasq)". (Verified.)

Comment: i did answer the question about rhe size of comm above.  I allocated 65535 bytes although I know PATH_MAX is 4K.  For current version, the waste is acceptable

Comment: Although `comm`  _does_ get clipped, it still suffers from the "name (spaces)" issue(s). That is, create a program thus: `cc -o 'name (spaces)' hello.c` and handle an invocation of: `./name\ \(spaces\)` BTW, I've parsed `/proc/X/stat` before. It _does_ have some unique info. But, I've found that parsing `/proc/X/status` to be my current "go to" method.

Comment: Thanks again, @CraigEstey I must admit I don't follow. If you mean that the fscanf may perceive such a program name as two fields rather than one - I have to give that one to you.  A problem for another day - there are no running scripts or programs with that condition running on this system; of that I can assure you.  But we've digressed. Again, my goal is not (as much) to solve this programming problem, but to more easily find the source (pun unintentional) of the problem this time and if it happens again.  I truly appreciate your consideration. Oh, and code now checks RC.  52 fields.

Comment: One question for you @CraigEstey if you're still there:  Have you found a reliable means other than /proc/[pid]/stat that you can obtain the start time of a process (relative to boot, or otherwise)?  That may be the last important field that I cannot find.

Comment: There _may_ be a simpler/direct way, but I believe I've done this in the past. Look at: `starttime ; // Start tine (in clock ticks) after system boot (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK))` from `/proc/X/stat`. To get system boot time: parse `/proc/uptime` (first number) gives elapsed time since boot, the _system_  `uptime`. `boot_time = time() - uptime`. You can use (e.g.) `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,...)` instead of `time()` for hires. So, `process_abs_start_time = boot_time + starttime`. Per the comment, scale `starttime` to seconds first.

Comment: Thanks @CraigEstey - that's why I used /proc/[pid]/stat instead of alternatives.  Nearest I can deteremine, only .../stat gives me that field in any format.

Comment: have you tried compiling with address sanitizer (`-fsanitize=address` passed to gcc) on?

Comment: I was going to suggest to look at what the `uptime` program does, so I did it myself. It parses `/proc/stat` (i.e. _not_ `/proc/X/stat`) and looks for `btime XXX`. This is the boot time in absolute seconds. This is a much better way to get the system start/boot time as it's "stable". With `/proc/uptime` the first number is constantly changing

Comment: Good tip, @CraigEstey. Currently, for uptime I'm doing: if ((rc = sysinfo(&s_info)) == 0) uptime = s_info.uptime;   But earlier I was tempted to go after /proc/uptime for this value.

Comment: I assumed there was a syscall [as BSD likes this approach]. Most of the code I use to access this stuff is `perl`, so I do `/proc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the inception of the called process (procNameFromCmdline) we can see that every parameter is incorrect

This most likely means that GDB didn't skip the function prolog (like it's supposed to). Most likely because of [this](https://www.cygwin.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25901).

If you do another `step` or `next`, parameters will suddenly become correct again.

Note that the above bug has been fixed in newer GDB versions, so updating GDB is another solution.

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right!  I was hesitant to proceed beyond the point that I perceived the program being corrupt (why move forward from there?) but you were completely correct.  Executing "step" resolved the issue for me.  YAY - although I did lose about half of my already rare hair in the process of evaluating every character of the source code!  :)

Comment: @Dennis You could also simply update GDB -- newer versions handle the function prolog correctly.